# Put call in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript

This is my service method , where I need to do the put call to an API by passing an id. Is this the correct way, bcoz I am not able to hit my .put URL

```
 ENDPOINTS = {
        SAMPLE: "/sample",
      };
```

This is my service method:

```
    updateApi(): Promise<any> {
        const config = {
          headers: {
            accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        };

        const data = {
           // data 
        };
 const id = sample.id;
        return http
          .put(`${this.ENDPOINTS.SAMPLE}${id}`, data, config)
          .then((response) => {
            return response.data;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            throw error;
          });
      }
```

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking.  You'd call your `updateApi()` function wherever you need to call it in your application.  What have you tried and what isn't working?

Comment: plz check the updated question

Comment: Where do you define the variable `sample`?  According to the error message, it's a string.  And a string indeed does not have a property called `id`.

Comment: Are you perhaps using a JSON string that needs to be parsed? The answer is hidden in whatever is in the `sample` variable, so only you can really solve it at the moment.

Comment: sample is a model class which contains id as a string. and that id i need to pass in put url

Comment: My point is, you need to debug and log what the value of `sample` is, the error says it's a string, so seeing what it looks like should give you an idea of the problem.

Comment: @Singh Please do not edit the original code provided in your question as you start resolving issues, without also updating your current issue(s) in your question too. It causes confusion for current and future readers, making your question almost pointless to have posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is the line `const {id} = sample.id;`

This should instead be: `const { id } = sample;` or the equivalent `const id = sample.id`.

In addition, your API endpoint is missing a trailing `/`, so you should include it in your `.put()` call.

Example: `${this.ENDPOINTS.SAMPLE}/${id}`

Comment: yeah it will be const id = sample.id. is this thing correct, .put(`${this.ENDPOINTS.SAMPLE}${id}`, data, config). Bcoz i am not able to hit the URL

Comment: You are also missing a slash in your API endpoint/URL. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you have any reason for using `http` here but if you are flexible then try `fetch` API available in react.

```js
      const requestOptions = {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
        body: data
      };

      fetch(`${ENDPOINTS.SAMPLE}/${sample.id}`, requestOptions)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => this.setState({ // update data here }));
```

If you are directly making call to API in your component then above code can be placed inside `componentDidMount`.

Let me know if you face any issue!

Comment: I am able to hit the url but getting 404,so i think approach is wrong! id is something i want to pass in my put call. but where do i store it , i have no idea. So right now I am storing it in the model class, i.e sample. Is it a correct approach? I am new to reactjs completely

Comment: First of all, you want to pass `id` as query param or inside request body ? Also ReactJS uses JavaScript, it doesn't have anything of it's own. (FYI)

Comment: id is a path param

Comment: Okay here is the thing, if you are getting `404` then your URL is not correct, please check on that. Secondly about `id`, it doesn't really matter where you store it, it can vary depends on project architecture. I would suggest to simply pass it to url and not store anywhere.

Comment: url is correct, i am getting this id as undefined in Network tab

Comment: Okay in that case I will need to see the whole flow of how `id` is stored currently. Is it something static like hardcoded value ?

Comment: Id is something which I am getting while uploading a file in my frontend. I have to make use of that id to update the content of the file!

Comment: Thanks for these details but to help you further I will have to see the complete flow of `id`. Would you be able to share those codes with me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213173/discussion-between-singh-and-milind-agrawal).